# Which bars will be visible (shown) after matplotlib ax.bar() call?

Tags: matplotlib, bar-chart

Assume that we are plotting bar plots in matplotlib.

When the values are in the same range we can see all bars.

However, when some values are too high we can not see the bars with very low values.

Is there a way to know which bars are shown (visible) or not after the call of ax.bar()
using its returned object of type class 'matplotlib.container.BarContainer'?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5
# menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27) # All 5 bars are shown
menMeans = (20, 35000, 30, 35, 27) # Only 2nd bar is shown
menStd =   (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)

ind = np.arange(N)  
width = 0.35       

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, menMeans, width, color='royalblue', yerr=menStd)

ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores')
ax.set_xticks(ind)
ax.set_xticklabels( ('a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5') )

plt.show()
```

These commands write that all bars are plotted.
However, they aren't shown in the final plot.

```
for i in rects1.patches: 
  print(i.get_height(),i.get_bbox(), i.get_visible())
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you use a log scale for the y-axis, it won't be hidden, but is there any reason not to use it? `ax.set_yscale('log')`

Comment: How about setting the exact value in the annotation?

Comment: I mean if you use the y-axis as a log scale and annotate the exact value.

Comment: When you plot your bars, Matplotlib has only a discrete number of pixels to allocate to the highest bar, if the ratio between values (hi/lo) is so large that less than half a pixel is allocated to a short bar, that short bar can not be plotted.  If you want to represent in a single graph data that has different orders of magnitude you HAVE to use a logarithmic axis.

Comment: **All the bars are plotted**, alas, some bars in screen coordinates (i.e., pixels) have a zero height. But they are plotted. Please get over it.

Comment: @gboffi how to get the bars with zero height?